# Arduino UNO Help Needed

Tags: arduino

So, I am pretty sure on what to do here, but since I will need to do it in 10 minutes in my test, I have to set up an Arduino UNO to play a 3-LED-sequence in which every LED turns on for a second, then the next one to the left, and then the third one, repeated constantly until you press a button (hardware, on the board), then the sequence turns around, and the third LED is now the third, the first one is the last, etc.
This is what I've made so far:

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);   
  delay(1000);                  
  digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);    
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW);    
  delay(1000); 

}
if (<Button Pressed condition>) 
{
  digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);   
  delay(1000);                  
  digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);    
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);    
  delay(1000);
}
else
{
digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);   
  delay(1000);                  
  digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);    
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW);    
  delay(1000); 
}
```

Am I missing anything? and also, what do I have to change if I have a Pull-Up or Pull-Down resistance?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you do need to do your own work, especially if you are going to be taking a test!

However, from the point of view of developing your own answer, approach this problem in increments.

First, get a version of your code to work for ONE Led, where it is on and then off and pressing a button causes it to be immediately off (if on) or immediately on (if off).  Even this version is NOT easy because you will need to code an Interrupt Service Routine (ISR).

Once you have this working for one Led, create a copy of code and name it version 2.  Get version 2 to work for TWO Leds.  To do this you will need to use all of the knowledge you gained in doing the first version.  If you have a problem with Version 2 you can always go back to V1 and do a small change to test the problem using code that you know works!

Finally, do V3 along the same lines, only for all three LEDs.

Someone giving you the answer will **not** help you do well on a test.  Good Luck, and please return to StackOverflow with specific questions.